# Google mobile vision library 11.8.0 is not recognized

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am using Gradle version 4.1 with Android plugin version 3.0.0 in Android Studio 3.0. 
In my project, I am trying to use Google Play service's Mobile Vision library.

If I configure dependencies in Gradle build script for my app with

```
    dependencies {
    ...
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0' 
    }
```

then Gradle syncs with my Android project fine, but flags a warning message : " **A newer version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision than 10.2.0 is available: 11.8.0** ".
But if I configure my build.gradle with

```
    dependencies{
    ...
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
    }
```

then I get this following error : " **Error:(29, 20) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0** "

The rest of the build.gradle script (without dependencies section) looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "{something something}"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me out on this ?

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.

Something like this-

```
allprojects {
    ...

    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you only need to use `google()` when using Gradle 4.1 or later (as per https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have google maven repo in your main `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

Comment: This solve my issue. Thanks a lot!